# Will searchable field give me better performance in azure cognitive search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We use azure search and there are some collection (size upto 40 or 50) fields, for example:
CacheId:["1","2","1a"].

Then we may have query like: for items belong to CacheId 1 or 2, retrieve facet for field "Category".

The index has around 500k documents and sometimes we do see slowdown or throttle when it is busy.

I am wondering if we can change this CacheId field from Collection to a space separated string (e.g. "1 2 1a"), and then use the standard analyser for the field.

After that, I can run query such as:

```
search=CacheId:2b 1&searchMode=any
```

This will give all the documents that has cacheId 2b or 1 and then I add facet in query.

However, I couldn't find any documentation to see if this way will be any quicker comparing to current Collection field.

Does anyone have more knowledge on this? Will it make things better, worse or no difference at all?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Search has [some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-analysis) on how to analyze, monitor, and improve query performance. You could use those resources to try and optimize your current queries first.

If no optimizations can be made, your best bet will be to test the performance of both setups using your production queries. I'm doubtful that moving from a collection to a string will improve performance, especially if following the best practices mentioned in the linked docs, but you can gather data through testing to be sure.

Comment: Use load testing in Postman or use a dedicated tool like JMeter. I agree that strings or collections should not make much difference. It depends on your content, your index and the property settings you use.